# Use XSS to Bypass CSRF protection with x-csrf token in header

Tags: xss

I found a web page is vulnerable to XSS vulnerability and I would like to bypass the CSRF protection with the XSS vulnerability.

However, the CSRF protection method is to use x-csrf-token in the request header and it is not in the response header.

Is there a way to bypass the CSRF protection method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to decode CSRF token, it could be hashed using MD5, SHA or etc.
2. If CSRF set in cookie, try to read cookie and inject it in request.
3. Try to find CSRF token in JS code in page, then inject it in request.